# Why text in some of my Angular Material component appears to be white?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In some of my `mat` components, like `mat-tab-group`, the text appears to be white and invisible. My theme is pink blue-grey. here's the code

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First" > Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The image of what's going on:

[image: happening2]

When highlighted by the cursor
[image: happening1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay what I think he problem was that my theme was dark theme. I went to `project/index.html` and added

```html
<body class="mat-typography mat-app-background">
```

which changed background to dark

Answer (score 1):

This is the common problem occuring since Angular Material version 0.11. Components inside toolbars are being colored white. This problem occurs in e.g.: md-toolbar, md-fab-actions, md-raised, and mat-tab.